# pie charts in R where slices represent the frequency of values in the columns of the data set

Tags: r, charts, pie-chart

I want to make pie charts for each column of my dataframe, where the slices represent the frequency, in which the values in the columns appear. For instance, the following will produce a data frame with 3 columns, and will round the numbers down to single digits.

```
test1<-rnorm(200,mean = 20, sd = 2)
test2<-rnorm(200,mean=20, sd =1)
test3<-rnorm(200,mean=20, sd =3)
testdata<-cbind(test,test2,test3)
testdata <-round(testdata,0)
```

So I would need to have 3 pie charts, where the slices represent the number of times, in which a given value appears in the respective column (with the name of the column on top of the pie chart, if possible)
So far, I have tried `pie(frame(testdata$test1))` but it works for creating a single pie chart, and my real data has 25 columns. On top of that, trying to pass a "main=" argument to name it, results in error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please **please** do not make pie charts. They have the worst information - to -space used ratio of almost any kind of chart in existence. Generate a bar chart or Pareto chart &  you will have a much more comprehensible result.

Answer (score -1):

`ggplot2` is the go-to library to make nice plots. To have 3 different pie-plots one needs to adjust the data a bit, which is done with some `tidyverse`-functions.

```
test1<-rnorm(200,mean = 20, sd = 2)
test2<-rnorm(200,mean=20, sd =1)
test3<-rnorm(200,mean=20, sd =3)
testdata<-cbind(test1,test2,test3)
testdata <-round(testdata,0)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

plotdata <- testdata %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(names(.),names_to = "data1", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(data1) %>% 
  count(value) 

ggplot(plot_data, aes( x = "", y = n, fill = factor(value))) +
  geom_col(width = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~data1)
```

[image]

Comment: the base package `plot` tools work just fine for simple stuff too!  In any case, please don't encourage anyone ever anywhere to generate pie charts.